# Unable to access custom field in for loop from another class

Tags: apex, map

I am getting "Variable does not exist:field" error when I am trying to refer to a field in For loop from a different class, below are my classes

Class1:

```
public static Map<String,sobject> bankIDs = new Map<String,sObject>(); //fetch generic object
   @InvocableMethod
   public static void class1(Request[] requests){
        --
        Class2 objSel = new Class2();
        for(sObject obj : accsel.branches(allValues, objectName)){
            bankIDs.put(obj.customField__c,obj); //ERROR
            //Variable does not exist: customField__c
        }
        --
   }
```

Class2:

```
public with sharing class Class2 implements Iclass2{
   public List<sObject> sobjList = new List<sObject>();
   public List<Sobject> branches(Set<String> allValues,string objectName){         
        Map<string,Queries__mdt> qMap = new Map<string,Queries__mdt>();
        //fetch query from custom metadata, I have included my custom field in the query
        for(Queries__mdt amq:[Select QualifiedApiName,Query__c from Queries__mdt where QualifiedApiName=:objectName])
        {
            qMap.put(amq.QualifiedApiName,amq);
        }
        //get complete query with allValues
        string query='Select '+qMap.get(objectName).Query__c +':allValues';
        if(!allValues.isEmpty()){            
            List<sObject> sobjList=Database.query(query);
        }
        return sobjList;//I can see the expected output in my debug log
    }
}
```

how can I map my  into bankIds, Lemme know,

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sObject class is the parent of all DML-enabled objects. Because of the concept of polymorphism, if you call an object an sObject, you can only access methods and properties available to all sObjects. Fortunately, Apex gives you a way to access those fields, documented in "[Dynamic DML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm)."

To get and set values, use get and put (respectively):

```
bankIDs.put((string)obj.get('customfield__c'),obj);
```

Note that the return type for get is always an Object, so you have to [cast to the appropriate type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting.htm) (here, `string`).

Comment: Thank you again @sfdcfox, also thanks for the documents, it's working now!

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I have one more question from the above code, 
In this for loop, for(sObject obj : accsel.branches(allValues, objectName)){bankIDs.put(obj.customField__c,obj);  }, I am getting bankIDs as empty list because the sObject value is also blank, it is not taking the Object Name, How can I pass the sObject(as Account) in for loop? 
Let me know if I can post here or create a new post, thank you.

Comment: @user62694 Being able to see more code would be helpful. A new post would be better, since you can include all the code you need to.